# Intent not passes my to my second Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

The reason is that ones i  fill in my user name, and password and click login button it is loads again at page requires tu fill user name, and password here is my source code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mTextUserName;
private EditText mTextPassword;
public String user_name;
public String pass_word;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUserName);
    mTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);


    final Button mButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            user_name = mTextUserName.getText().toString();
            pass_word = mTextPassword.getText().toString();
           // i am passing this intent 
            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);

            goToNextActivity.putExtra("username", user_name);
            goToNextActivity.putExtra("password", pass_word);

            startActivity(goToNextActivity);


        }
    });
}
```

and in mine ViewActivity also

```
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
public String pass_word;
public String user_name;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(20);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                //here i get them 
                getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
                getIntent().getStringExtra("password");




    webView.loadUrl("http://intranet.mdis.uz/");
}
```

but this doest works(( i spended 8 hours on research but nothing helped me

Comment: When you press the button, are you not going to the ViewActivity? What if you try Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewActivity.class)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You call `getIntent().getStringExtra("username");` and `getIntent().getStringExtra("password");` but don't do anything with the return values.

Comment: The fact that the activity has changed means user has been logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try it.

Do the modification like this once and see plz...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mTextUserName;
private EditText mTextPassword;
public String user_name;
public String pass_word;
ConnectionClass cc;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUserName);
    mTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);

    cc=new ConnectionClass(this);
    final Button mButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            user_name = mTextUserName.getText().toString();
            pass_word = mTextPassword.getText().toString();

            user_name=Uri.encode(user_name); // you can encode your parameters so that it does not throw exception for e.g it will replace a space as %20 otherwise if user enters special character error will come.. :)
            pass_word=Uri.encode(pass_word); // same as above

            String url="http://myserver.com/login.php?username="+user_name"&password="+user_name; // this is your server page url and passing username and password in plain url u can test it in browser to verify its working :)

            new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>() // new android versions does not allow network operations on main thread but need to do asynchronously...
            {

               @Override
               protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

               return cc.getServerResponse(params[0]);
              }

              @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  // this method runs on UI thread and is called when background process is done to make it more fancy u can use onPreExecute() to show a loader and dismiss the dialog here :)
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result!=null)
            {
                if(result.equals("1")  // assuming u r returning "1" if successful.
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Successful", 2000).show();
                    Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
                    goToNextActivity.putExtra("username", user_name);
                    goToNextActivity.putExtra("password", pass_word);
                    startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                }
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "Network problem...", 2000).show();
        }

            }.execute(url);


            }


        }
    });
}
```

Here is the ConnectionClass

```
public class ConnectionClass {


    Context context;
    public ConnectionClass(Context ctx) {
        this.context=ctx;
    }


    public String getServerResponse(String urlLink)
    {

        try 
        {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost http_get = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse responses;
            responses = client.execute(http_get);
            if (responses != null) 
            {
                InputStream in = responses.getEntity().getContent(); 
                String a = convertStreamToString(in);
               // Log.i("RETURN",a+"");
                return a;
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }



    String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {

             //Toast.makeText(context, e.toString()+" io2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                is.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                //Toast.makeText(context, e.toString()+" io3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps u :)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is wrong:

```
Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);
```

you should not use `ApplicationContext` when you trying to start new activity. Try this:

```
Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
```

**EDIT:**

Try this, it should send data via POST:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(20);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");

    String data = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

    webView.postUrl("http://intranet.mdis.uz/", EncodingUtils.getBytes(data, "base64"));
```

Comment: again the same result

Comment: yeah if you want i can give you mine credentials for you to try

Comment: `String data = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;` change this line to `String data = "edit-name=" + username + "&edit-pass=" + password;`

Comment: again the same result

Comment: It is not `edit-name` and `edit-pass` the form inputs. It is `name` and `pass`. Something like: `String data = "name=" + username + "&pass=" + password;`

Comment: maybe try  
    String user_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    String pass_word = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");

    String data = "username=" + user_name + "&password=" + pass_word; this one ?

Comment: No, as mentioned above try `String data = "name=" + username + "&pass=" + password;`

Comment: again the same result